# I need a script that opens one by one excel link then scrapes info and save it

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have some doubts about my below script. Basically, I have an excel file with lots of links in it and I need to extract some info from them. But the problem is my code only picks the last piece of data, not for all the data.

I need a script that opens each excel file then scrapes the info and saves into any format like CSV or excel.

Please find the current script which I am using.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\india\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")

exampleFile = open("Desktop/Test.csv")
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
exampleData = list(exampleReader)
final = []
for item in exampleData:
    final.append(item[0])
for url in final:
    Template=(url)
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'dp'})
records = []
for item in results:
    record = extract_record(item)
    if record:
        records.append(record)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Move the `driver.get(url)` etc. code into the `for url in final` loop.

Comment: Hi Jarmod, Thanks for the reply could you please help me to understand how can I do this as I'm not getting this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is written incorrectly:

```
for url in final:
    Template=(url)

driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'dp'})
records = []
for item in results:
    record = extract_record(item)
    if record:
        records.append(record)
```

The actual code that reads the URL and scrapes it needs to be inside the `for` loop. It needs to execute for every URL. As written, you iterate over the URLs in `final`, and then you execute the code to scrape the URL, hence it only scrapes the last one.

Change it to something like:

```
records = []

for url in final:
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'dp'})

    for item in results:
        record = extract_record(item)
        if record:
            records.append(record)
```

That will also accumulate all results, for all URLs, into `records`.

Comment: Hi Jarmod, Thanks for your reply but by using the above code I have getting the below error.

Comment: ``` ```InvalidArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9fcc7dad3307> in <module>
     15 for url in final:
     16     Template=(url)
---> 17     driver.get(url)
     18     soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
     19     results = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'dp'})```

Comment: ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334 
    335     @property```

Comment: ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))```

Comment: ```C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)```

Comment: All we did was correct your for loop indentation problem and remove the seemingly pointless `Template=(url)`. If you now have a problem using BeautifulSoup, as you appear to, then it's probably worth a new question with the latest code and correctly formatted exception output, because working through this in comments is not practical.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jarmod you are amazing it was a great help now I am able to extract the correct data as I expected.

Comment: Hi Jarmod,

This Program is running fine but now i have some minor issue please help me in this too.
I have a script where I extract data from a website using multiple URLs in excel. but the problem is when the extraction interrupts, then the whole data is lost and nothing save in an excel file. Now I need something that opens URL from an excel and scrapes data one by one save the excel with every iteration. Please let me know if you need information.

Thanks

Comment: I would start a new question, include the code as it is now, and ask for help. But first, try to change your code to do what you want. The code would look like: `for url in urls: fetch URL, open output file,  write output, close output file, end for loop`

Comment: Hi Jordan as I'm new in python actually it's a little bit confusing for me to understand this very sort hint.